# Natural merge: mergesort that uses already sorted subarrays

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, sorting, mergesort

The code bellow is my implementation for the natural merge exercise in Robert Sedgwick's Algorithms book:

> Write a version of bottom-up mergesort that takes advantage of order
>   in the array by proceeding as follows each time it needs to ﬁnd two
>   arrays to merge: ﬁnd a sorted subarray (by incrementing a pointer
>   until ﬁnding an entry that is smaller than its predecessor in the
>   array), then ﬁnd the next, then merge them.

```
def merge(a, lo, mi, hi):
    aux_lo = deque(a[lo:mi])
    aux_hi = deque(a[mi:hi])

    for i in range(lo, hi):
        if len(aux_lo) and len(aux_hi):
            a[i] = aux_lo.popleft() if aux_lo[0] < aux_hi[0] else aux_hi.popleft()
        elif len(aux_lo) or len(aux_hi):
            a[i] = aux_lo.popleft() if aux_lo else aux_hi.popleft()

def find_next_stop(a, start):
    if start >= len(a)-1:
        return start

    stop = start + 1
    if a[start] < a[stop]:
        while(stop<len(a)-1 and a[stop] <= a[stop+1]):
            stop += 1
    else:
        while(stop<len(a)-1 and a[stop] >= a[stop+1]):
            stop += 1

        _stop = stop
        while(start<_stop):
            a[_stop], a[start] = a[start], a[_stop]
            start += 1
            _stop -= 1
    return stop

def natural_merge(a):
    lo = hi = 0
    while(True):
        lo = hi
        mi = find_next_stop(a, lo)
        if lo == 0 and mi == len(a) - 1:
            return
        hi = find_next_stop(a, mi)
        if mi == hi == len(a)-1:
            lo = hi = 0
            continue
        merge(a, lo, mi, hi)
```

I referenced [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/87334/77243).

Comment: Add docstrings and typed arguments. Otherwise it's not bad

Comment: A pity the code presented is uncommented but for a cryptic `this takes more space than allowed` - extra constraint(s)? (There's more than one error in `I take this anwser as a referenced.`.)

Comment: @greybeard Thanks for helping me point out the errors.

Comment: I've reverted your change. The code in the question should not be updated to ensure that answers stay relevant.

Comment: @Josay But if you could update your answer according to my change reverted by you, I'd appreciate it very much.

Comment: @lerner I've updated my answer accordingly and added many other small details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Tests and bugs**

Your code looks mostly good. Before trying to go and change the code to see what can be improved. I usually try to write a few simple tests. This is even easier when you have a reference implementation that can be compared to your function. In your case, I wrote:

```
TESTS = [
    [],
    [0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    [5, 2, 3, 1, 0, 4],
    [5, 2, 5, 3, 1, 3, 0, 4, 5],
]

for t in TESTS:
    print(t)
    ref_lst, tst_lst = list(t), list(t)
    ref_lst.sort()
    natural_merge(tst_lst)
    print(ref_lst, tst_lst)
    assert ref_lst == tst_lst
```

which leads to a first comment: the empty list is not handled properly and the function never returns.

**Improving `merge`**

The case `elif len(aux_lo) or len(aux_hi)` seems complicated as we check `if aux_lo` just after. Things would be clearer if we were to split in two different cases:

```
    if len(aux_lo) and len(aux_hi):
        a[i] = aux_lo.popleft() if aux_lo[0] < aux_hi[0] else aux_hi.popleft()
    elif len(aux_lo):
        a[i] = aux_lo.popleft()
    elif len(aux_hi):
        a[i] = aux_hi.popleft()
```

Also, we could reuse the fact that in a boolean context, list are considered to be true if and only if they are not empty to write:

```
for i in range(lo, hi):
    if aux_lo and aux_hi:
        a[i] = aux_lo.popleft() if aux_lo[0] < aux_hi[0] else aux_hi.popleft()
    elif aux_lo:
        a[i] = aux_lo.popleft()
    elif aux_hi:
        a[i] = aux_hi.popleft()
```

**Improving `find_next_stop`**

You don't need so many parenthesis.

You could store `len(a) - 1` in a variable in order not to re-compute it every time.

The name `_stop` is pretty ugly. I do not have any great suggestion for an alternative but `end` seems okay-ish.

**More tests... and more bugs**

I wanted to add a few tests to verify an assumption... and I stumbled upon another issue.

Here is the corresponding test suite:

```
TESTS = [
    [],
    [0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    [5, 2, 3, 1, 0, 4],
    [5, 2, 5, 3, 1, 3, 0, 4, 5],
    [5, 2, 5, 3, 1, 3, 0, 4, 5, 3, 1, 0, 1, 5, 2, 5, 3, 1, 3, 0, 4, 5],
]
```

---

Taking into account my comments and the fix you tried to add in the question, we now have:

```
from collections import deque

def merge(a, lo, mi, hi):
    aux_lo = deque(a[lo:mi])
    aux_hi = deque(a[mi:hi])

    for i in range(lo, hi):
        if aux_lo and aux_hi:
            a[i] = aux_lo.popleft() if aux_lo[0] < aux_hi[0] else aux_hi.popleft()
        elif aux_lo:
            a[i] = aux_lo.popleft()
        elif aux_hi:
            a[i] = aux_hi.popleft()

def find_next_stop(a, start):
    upper = len(a) - 1
    if start >= upper:
        return start

    stop = start + 1
    if a[start] <= a[stop]:
        while stop < upper and a[stop] <= a[stop+1]:
            stop += 1
    else:
        while stop < upper and a[stop] >= a[stop+1]:
            stop += 1

        end = stop
        while start < end:
            a[end], a[start] = a[start], a[end]
            start += 1
            end -= 1
    return stop

def natural_merge(a):
    upper = len(a) - 1
    if upper <= 0:
        return
    lo = hi = 0
    while True:
        lo = hi
        mi = find_next_stop(a, lo)
        if lo == 0 and mi == upper:
            return
        hi = find_next_stop(a, mi)
        if mi == hi == upper:
            lo = hi = 0
        else:
            merge(a, lo, mi, hi)



TESTS = [
    [],
    [0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    [5, 2, 3, 1, 0, 4],
    [5, 2, 5, 3, 1, 3, 0, 4, 5],
    [5, 2, 5, 3, 1, 3, 0, 4, 5, 3, 1, 0, 1, 5, 2, 5, 3, 1, 3, 0, 4, 5],
]

for t in TESTS:
    print(t)
    ref_lst, tst_lst = list(t), list(t)
    ref_lst.sort()
    natural_merge(tst_lst)
    print(ref_lst, tst_lst)
    assert ref_lst == tst_lst
```

**More improvements in `find_next_stop`**

We have a `while` loop but we can compute the number of iterations we'll need: it corresponds to have the distance between `start` and `stop`. We could use a `for _ in range` loop to perform this. It has pros and cons but one of the key aspect is that we do not need to change `start` and `stop`, thus we don't need to copy the value in a variable.

```
    for k in range((1 + stop - start) // 2):
        i, j = start + k, stop - k
        a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
```

**More improvements in `natural_merge`**

A few steps can be used to re-organise the function:

- see that we can move the assignment `lo = hi` from the beginning of the loop to the end of the loop with no impact
- realise that it is already done in the first branch of the test already so move it to the `else` block exclusively
- see that the initialisation of `hi` is not required anymore
- notice that the condition `mi == upper` is checked in 2 places (with the same value of `mi` and `upper` and that if `lo != 0`, we see that `mi == upper` directly leads to `find_next(a, mi)` returning `upper` and thus ending with `mi == hi == upper` and thus to the assignment `lo = hi = 0`.

At this stage, we have:

```
def natural_merge(a):
    upper = len(a) - 1
    if upper <= 0:
        return
    lo = 0
    while True:
        mi = find_next_stop(a, lo)
        if mi == upper:
            if lo == 0:
                return
            lo = hi = 0
        else:
            hi = find_next_stop(a, mi)
            merge(a, lo, mi, hi)
            lo = hi
```

We can go further:

- the assignment `hi = 0` has no effect
- we can reorganise conditions

We'd get

```
def natural_merge(a):
    upper = len(a) - 1
    if upper <= 0:
        return
    lo = 0
    while True:
        mi = find_next_stop(a, lo)
        if mi != upper:
            hi = find_next_stop(a, mi)
            merge(a, lo, mi, hi)
            lo = hi
        elif lo == 0:
            return
        else:
            lo = 0
```

Interestingly, removing `lo = hi` leads a much more efficient code on my benchmark: the function returns much more quickly (because we always have `lo == 0`, we get out of the loop as soon as `mi == upper`) and the list is still fully sorted.

```
def natural_merge(a):
    upper = len(a) - 1
    if upper <= 0:
        return
    while True:
        mi = find_next_stop(a, 0)
        if mi == upper:
            return
        hi = find_next_stop(a, mi)
        merge(a, 0, mi, hi)
```

This looked surprising at first but thinking about it, it looks like this may be the way this algorithm is supposed to be.

Comment: I've realized the meaning of the last snippet in your answer, awesome!